# Meaning of vocabulary in context

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

What is  the meaning of ?

> cunningly contrived

whereas *contrived* means  forcefully and *cunning* means attractive.

Source: The sentence came from Question 2 on [this GRE practice question](http://www.majortests.com/gre/text_completion_test08).

`2. We were not fooled by his (i)____ arguments; his plan was (ii)____. That even he was (iii)____ by his own reasoning was apparent from his unenthusiastic demeanor.`

One of the possible answers for (ii) is *cunningly contrived*.

Comment: *Contrived* is not a form of *contrite*; neither word means *forcefully*.  *Cunning* does not mean *attractive*.  I think you should look up [*cunning*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/cunning_1) and [*contrive*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/contrive?q=contrive) in a dictionary.

Comment: sorry I have miss typed

Comment: Can you please provide more context to this question, including what the dictionary says about "cunning" and "contrived" and what you don't understand about it? As it stands we can't really give you anything that a dictionary couldn't answer just as fully, and that is off-topic (see meta [here](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/a/384/307)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word *cunning* in this context means *deceitful* or *dishonest*. A *cunningly contrived* argument would be one where someone was arguing about something by twisting the facts and being more dishonest than straightforward.

Even though [OneLook](http://onelook.com/?w=cunningly&ls=a) shows *cunning* as meaning *artful or attractive*, the meaning you really want for this context is [Collins Def. #1](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/cunningly):

> *crafty and shrewd, esp. in deception; sly*

In the [test question](http://www.majortests.com/gre/text_completion_expl.php?exp=543030382432243933), *cunningly contrived* would be a much better answer than *clearly brilliant*, but it's still inferior to *obviously untenable*.